# Adobe Flash Professional is not saving a documents (FLAs) changes when only component data is updated

Tags: flash

From within Adobe Flash CS6, when I save, even after being promoted to save, sometimes, but not always, my updates are not saved.

I have custom text component that is being updated in a lot of FLA files. If I update, publish, then save, then reopen, the published file is correct and the newly re-opened document looks like it did before I updated it.

Any thoughts?

My current work around is listed as an answer below.

Comment: Are you using a Flash project?

Comment: No. I am developing in FlashDevelop and use that to organize my project. I open FLAs in Flash Pro.

Comment: Is tere an AuthorTimeSharedAssets.fla in the directory with the problem flas?

Comment: no, but there are many shared assets in another directory.

Comment: I think you'll find it's related to that. You're saving the change and then the shared asset overwrites your change. Make sure you only work on one file that uses the shared library at a time. In extreme cases, uncheck update automatically, make the change, then check it.

Comment: Shared libraries are the bane of my existence...

Comment: Yes, it has to be a fairly large project to make it worth the hassle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The work around I am currently using is to always "save as" instead of "save".